# Java StreamAPI: Найти sum, average , сгруппировав по нескольким полям

Tags: java, java-stream

Имеется класс сущности

```
public class CenterReportDto {
     ZonedDateTime date;
     int centerId;
     int amount;
     float percent;
}
```

и список сущностей

```
List<CenterReportDto> entityList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Делаю:

```
 entityList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getDate().getMonth(),Collectors.summingInt(CenterReportDto::getAmount)))
             .forEach((s,j) -> System.out.println(s + "-" + j) );

  entityList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getDate().getMonth(),
                            Collectors.averagingDouble(CenterReportDto::getPercent)))
                    .forEach((s,j) -> System.out.println(s + "-" + j) );
```

и получаю:

```
JANUARY-7
FEBRUARY-9

JANUARY-3.5
FEBRUARY-4.5
```

Как скомбинировать два вызова чтобы найти сумму для amount и среднее для percent, а также сгруппировать по двум полям - month, center_id чтобы получить:

```
JANUARY - 123 - 7 -  3.5
FEBRUARY -123 - 9 - 4.5
JANUARY - 456 - 7 -  3.5
FEBRUARY -456 - 9 - 4.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ПРАВКА** (так как автор вопроса справедливо указал мне на неточность):

*первое решение* совсем не верное, так как считает среднее и сумму по одному полю, но зато показывает, какая хорошая вещь `summarizingXXX`

```
entityList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getDate().getMonth(), 
                                         Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getCenterId(), 
                                                               Collectors.summarizingInt( i -> i.getAmount()))))
          .forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach((k1, v1) -> System.out.println(k.toString() + " - " + k1.toString() + " - " + v1.getAverage() + " - " + v1.getSum())));
```

*второе решение* вроде бы верное: считает разные агрегатные показатели от разных полей

```
entityList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getDate().getMonth(),
                                         Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getCenterId(),
                                         Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                                                                      l -> {Integer sum = l.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(i -> i.getAmount()));
                                                                            Double avg = l.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(i -> i.getPercent()));
                                                                            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(sum, avg);
                                                                            }))))
          .forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach((k1, v1) -> System.out.println(k.toString() + " - " + k1.toString() + " - " + v1.getKey() + " - " + v1.getValue())));
```

Comment: Премного благодарен! То, что надо!

Comment: Спасибо за задачу, почитать про summarizingXXX было полезно

Comment: Не совсем так. Мне нужно найти сумму поля amount , а среднее - для поля percent

Comment: @harp1814 если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @harp1814 подумал (хитрющая задача) и составил второе решение

Comment: @hinotf Спасибо, теперь всё как надо.